# How do I clone a larger disk to a smaller disk, but retain sizes of the system partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10, ssd

I recently bought an SSD, and I am attempting to move the contents of my current drive to the new one. Using Todo Backup, I am able to do this, but the system partitions ("System Reserved" and "Recovery") end up being over 100GB in size on the new disk, taking up the space I need for storage.

The partitions in question are normally sized (<500MB) on my current disk. My current drive is 1TB, whereas the new SSD is 500GB. Also note that the recovery partition is hidden by default, and since I have a homebuilt PC it somehow came with the windows install. I assume it contains a copy of the operating system and repair tools, as I am unable to create rescue media when it is deleted (found this out the hard way).

[image: screenshot]

I am using Windows 10 on a UEFI system.

In Todo Backup, I can press the "edit" link next to the SSD when cloning, but it only allows me to resize via a slider, which is highly inaccurate.

Is there a method of cloning to a smaller SSD which retains the sizing of all partitions besides the main OS?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your current partition layout in disk management

Comment: http://imgur.com/qNOB7gg My current HDD. Don't have a screenshot of the SSD, I've been messing around with it. For the SSD, just make the two system partitions ~106GB.

Answer (score 0):

Go get a free tool by Mirray software called hdclone.  The free version limits the transfer to 20mb/s, but it will do what you are trying to do without doubt.

https://www.miray.de/products/sat.hdclone.html

I actually own a technicians license for this product because it has yet to fail on me when I need to clone a disk and resize the partitions, but like I said the free version will do everything you have outlined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete your recovery Partiton (Ofcourse only if you don't need it, but you usually don't, you still have all your data on your HDD), then create a Backup using Windows, burn a Recovery CD (After creating the Backup you will get asked to create one) and restart your pc with your Backup on a external drive, your Recovery CD/USB in your PC and your new SSD connected to the PC. Let Windows recreate your system from the Backup onto the SSD.

While creating the Backup you can select which Partitions you want

(Not sure about Recovery because its a hidden partition)

Here is a tutorial: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-pc